# Creating a basic Lightning App that will display an Einstein Analytics Dashboard using Lightning Out

Tags: lightning-aura-components, einstein-analytics, lightning-out

I'm trying to create a basic Lightning App that will display a Dashboard from Einstein Analytics.

Here's the code that I'm using.

CMP

```
<aura:component access="global" >
    <wave:waveDashboard dashboardId="Dashboard ID HERE" height="650" />
</aura:component>
```

APP

```
<aura:application access="Global" extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <aura:dependency resource="c:AnalyticsDashboardCMP" type="COMPONENT"/>
</aura:application>
```

When I'm trying to run the app I'm having the error:

```
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: ltng:outApp$controller$init [Incorrect usage of ltng:outApp. Refer to the 'Lightning Components Developer Guide' for correct usage]
Failing descriptor: {ltng:outApp$controller$init}
```

I tried using this and the dashboard is showing as expected.

```
<aura:application access="global"  >
    <c:AnalyticsDashboardCMP/>
</aura:application>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using this application on VF page? If not then `extends="ltng:outApp"` is not needed.

Comment: @rahulgawale appreciate your response, I'm planning to put this page outside Salesforce

Comment: Hi, Did you resolve it ? I am facing the same issue.